# Ckeditor 4.10 Copy and Paste does not work in MAC PRO - any work around?

Tags: macos, safari, ckeditor

Ckeditor 4.10 **Copy and Paste does not work** in new MAC PRO - any work around?
using Safari browser, They cant use control "C" or "V"

Thanks john